# Spatial join two data frames by nearest feature and date in R

Tags: r, r-sf

This question builds off of [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292403/spatial-joining-merging-two-spatial-points-data-frames-in-r-via-buffer) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71759624/join-two-spatial-data-frames-based-on-nearest-features-within-each-group) thread. Briefly, the code in these threads attempt to spatially join two spatial data frames according to the nearest features. The added layer of complexity that I am interested in is, in addition to join by nearest feature, to also join by date. However, i'm struggling to get the code working.

Below are the data frames and code that I tried (but failed):

```
df1 <- structure(list(lat1 = c(4417391, 4517826, 4435680, 4509372, 4449390, 
4449390), long1 = c(5557780, 5358439, 5328731, 5323168, 5519670, 
5519670), daydate = structure(c(16085, 16085, 16087, 16087, 16088, 
16088), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(lat2 = c(4394822, 4488830, 4417257, 4517995, 4435679
), long2 = c(5293795, 5418630, 5557927, 5358272, 5328084), daydate = structure(c(16085, 
16085, 16087, 16087, 16088), class = "Date"), temp = c(6L, 26L, 
13L, 30L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

df1
     lat1   long1    daydate
1 4417391 5557780 2014-01-15
2 4517826 5358439 2014-01-15
3 4435680 5328731 2014-01-17
4 4509372 5323168 2014-01-17
5 4449390 5519670 2014-01-18
6 4449390 5519670 2014-01-18

df2
     lat2   long2    daydate temp
1 4394822 5293795 2014-01-15    6
2 4488830 5418630 2014-01-15   26
3 4417257 5557927 2014-01-17   13
4 4517995 5358272 2014-01-17   30
5 4435679 5328084 2014-01-18    8

# Make df & df1 sf objects, and keep the coordinates as columns just in case.
df1 <- df1 %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("long1", "lat1"), remove = FALSE) %>%
  st_set_crs(2193)
df2 <- df2 %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("long2", "lat2"), remove = FALSE) %>%
  st_set_crs(2193)

# Join df with df1, based on the nearest feature:
df_near <- st_join(df1, df1, join = st_nearest_feature) %>%
  group_by(daydate)

Error in `st_as_sf()`:
! Must group by variables found in `.data`.
x Column `daydate` is not found.
```

The returned error makes 100% sense as the code is written as sequential steps, but i don't know how to tell R to simultaneously consider both steps. The main objective is to get the temp values from df2 to the correct rows of df1.

Extra information in my actual data: In my actual df1 there may be duplicates for both coordinate pairs (lat1 and long1) as well as daydate. My actual df2 has duplicate coordinate pairs and daydate, but the combination of coordinate pairs and daydate is always unique i.e. every row of df2 is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this approximately what you are looking for? I used {base} for this since it is IMO easier to handle when coordinating parts of two different tables... but I think `lapply(split(df1, 1:nrow(df1), ...)` would be approximately the same as applying `st_join()` `dplyr::rowwise()`?

*For each unique record / row* in `df1` calculate the *nearest* feature in the *subset of* `df2` that has the *same* `daydate`:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df1 <- data.frame(
  lat1 = c(4417391, 4517826, 4435680, 4509372, 4449390, 4449390),
  long1 = c(5557780, 5358439, 5328731, 5323168, 5519670, 5519670),
  daydate = structure(c(16085, 16085, 16087, 16087, 16088, 16088), class = "Date")
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  lat2 = c(4394822, 4488830, 4417257, 4517995, 4435679),
  long2 = c(5293795, 5418630, 5557927, 5358272, 5328084),
  daydate = structure(c(16085, 16085, 16087, 16087, 16088), class = "Date"),
  temp = c(6L, 26L, 13L, 30L, 8L)
)

df1 <- df1 %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long1", "lat1"), remove = FALSE) %>%
  st_set_crs(2193)

df2 <- df2 %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long2", "lat2"), remove = FALSE) %>%
  st_set_crs(2193)

res <- do.call('rbind', lapply(split(df1, 1:nrow(df1)), function(x) {
  st_join(x, df2[df2$daydate == unique(x$daydate),], join = st_nearest_feature)
}))

res
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 7 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 5323168 ymin: 4417391 xmax: 5557780 ymax: 4517826
#> Projected CRS: NZGD2000 / New Zealand Transverse Mercator 2000
#>      lat1   long1  daydate.x    lat2   long2  daydate.y temp
#> 1 4417391 5557780 2014-01-15 4488830 5418630 2014-01-15   26
#> 2 4517826 5358439 2014-01-15 4488830 5418630 2014-01-15   26
#> 3 4435680 5328731 2014-01-17 4517995 5358272 2014-01-17   30
#> 4 4509372 5323168 2014-01-17 4517995 5358272 2014-01-17   30
#> 5 4449390 5519670 2014-01-18 4435679 5328084 2014-01-18    8
#> 6 4449390 5519670 2014-01-18 4435679 5328084 2014-01-18    8
#>                  geometry
#> 1 POINT (5557780 4417391)
#> 2 POINT (5358439 4517826)
#> 3 POINT (5328731 4435680)
#> 4 POINT (5323168 4509372)
#> 5 POINT (5519670 4449390)
#> 6 POINT (5519670 4449390)

plot(st_geometry(res))
plot(df2 %>% 
       st_as_sf(coords = c("long2", "lat2"), remove = FALSE) %>%
       st_set_crs(2193) %>% 
       st_geometry(), add = T, pch = "*")
```

[image]

EDIT: here is the same thing using {data.table}

```r
df1 <- data.table(df1)
.nearest_samedate <- function(x) {
  st_join(st_as_sf(x), df2[df2$daydate == unique(x$daydate),], join = st_nearest_feature)
}

res <- df1[, .nearest_samedate(.SD), by = list(1:nrow(df1))]
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a go. my dfs are ~2k and ~240k rows big and it's been running for a while. I wonder if this process could be sped up using functions within the data.table package?

Comment: I added a few lines to do it data.table style. You are right that probably would be faster than the split/apply/combine / rowwise approach. Let me know how it benchmarks on the real data!

Comment: My code took approx an hour to run when i considered 1 static location with temperature values for a range of dates (df2 in OP). It took approx 10 hours to run last night when i increased the number of static locations to 2. I'm now running the code on 43 static locations (my full data set). Surprising or not surprising, the run time was just short of 1.5 h!

Answer (score 0):

You're doing everything (almost) right.  `df_near` doesn't have a column named `daydate` to group by. Since both `df_1` and `df_2` both have a column named `daydate`, the output has two columns for daydate named `daydate.x` and `daydate.y`. One from the left-hand side (df1), the other from the right-hand side(df2).

Using `group_by(daydate.x)` should work, buy you might want to check that the daydate columns are the same (or at least what you are expecting) between the dataframes.

```r
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df1 %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("long1", "lat1"), remove = FALSE) %>%
  st_set_crs(2193)
df2 <- df2 %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("long2", "lat2"), remove = FALSE) %>%
  st_set_crs(2193)

# Join df with df1, based on the nearest feature:
df_near <- st_join(df1, df2, join = st_nearest_feature) %>%
  group_by(daydate.x)

df_near
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 7 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 5323168 ymin: 4417391 xmax: 5557780 ymax: 4517826
#> Projected CRS: NZGD2000 / New Zealand Transverse Mercator 2000
#> # A tibble: 6 × 8
#> # Groups:   daydate.x [3]
#>      lat1   long1 daydate.x     lat2   long2 daydate.y   temp
#>     <dbl>   <dbl> <date>       <dbl>   <dbl> <date>     <int>
#> 1 4417391 5557780 2014-01-15 4417257 5557927 2014-01-17    13
#> 2 4517826 5358439 2014-01-15 4517995 5358272 2014-01-17    30
#> 3 4435680 5328731 2014-01-17 4435679 5328084 2014-01-18     8
#> 4 4509372 5323168 2014-01-17 4517995 5358272 2014-01-17    30
#> 5 4449390 5519670 2014-01-18 4417257 5557927 2014-01-17    13
#> 6 4449390 5519670 2014-01-18 4417257 5557927 2014-01-17    13
#> # … with 1 more variable: geometry <POINT [m]>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I think you need `st_join(df1, df2, ...)` not `st_join(df1, df1, ...)` , but then also you will need to deal with the fact that the nearest feature often does not occur on the same day.

Comment: @AndrewBrown That was a terrible typo, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @mrhellman Thank you for your proposed solution, but as Andrew Brown pointed out, your code does not seem to align dates as well.